# How do I make ProxyPassReverse rewrite relative redirects?

Tags: apache, proxypass

I have trouble getting relative redirects working with Apache and ProxyPassReverse. If I on the back-end server use absolute redirects ie. `Location: http://fake.frontend.com/cat`, everything is proxied like intended, however if I on the back-end server use relative redirects, ie. `Location: /cat` it does not work.

I am using Apache 2.4.25 on Debian.

I have the following configuration on the proxy server:

```
<Location /test/>
    ProxyPass http://fake.backend.local/
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ProxyPassReverse http://fake.backend.local/
    SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
    ProxyHTMLURLMap / /cat/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap fake.backend.local/ /cat/
    ProxyHTMLDocType "<!DOCTYPE html>"
</Location>
```

When I access the proxy server on `http://fake.frontend.com/cat/` the back-end server is redirected depending on being signed in or not. If not signed in I am redirected (302) to `/Signin`. If I am signed in I am redirected (302) to `/dashboard`. If the back-end application uses absolute paths in the location header, ie: `http://fake.backend.local/Signin` I then browser loads `http://fake.frontend.com/cat/Signin` like intended. However, if the backend application users relative paths in the location header, ie: `/Signin` the browser loads `http://fake.frontend.com/Signin` (notice the missing cat).

I want to use relative paths on the backend and still get redirected to `http://fake.frontend.com/cat/Signin`. How can I configure the proxy to work with relative location headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found and [article on askapache.com](https://www.askapache.com/hosting/reverse-proxy-apache/) that had an example where one should set the  `ProxyPassReverse` to `/`.

Changing to the following configuration solved my problem:

```
<Location /test/>
    ProxyPass http://fake.backend.local/
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ProxyPassReverse /
    SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
    ProxyHTMLURLMap / /cat/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap fake.backend.local/ /cat/
    ProxyHTMLDocType "<!DOCTYPE html>"
</Location>
```